# Number addition in Lua - avoiding negative values

Tags: math, lua, addition, negative-number

This is not hardcore math but I simply cannot find the correct function to make this in a smooth way.

Lets say I have 3 values. Cost1 Cost2 Cost3. Each have a value, I want to add them together into a final number, TotalCost.

```
Cost1+Cost2+Cost3 = TotalCost

Problem is, if any of Cost1/2/3 is negative, I want to make that a ZERO, ie;

Cost1 = -100
Cost2 = 50
Cost3 = 150

Cost1+Cost2+Cost3 = TotalCost 
equals
0 + 50 + 150 = 200
```

I know I have seen something with like (X*Math.Floor * 100) / 100 , to do just this, if im not completly mistaken.

Would be greatly apreciated if anyone could answer. I know its a basic question but I simply couldent figure out how (with a smart way that is) with the Math. functions.

Im coding in Lua: http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the shortest way to do this is `math.max(x,0)`.  So your expression would be:

```
math.max(Cost1,0) + math.max(Cost2,0) + math.max(Cost3,0)
```

Of course, you could also make a function out of it -- and you probably should, if you're going to use it for more than a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

The most straight-forward way is to use `if` statements to test if a number is negative.

This is another way:

```
function my_sum(...)
  sum = 0
  for k, v in ipairs{...} do
    sum = sum + (v > 0 and v or 0)
  end
  return sum
end

print(my_sum(-50, 50, 100))  -- 150
```

The expression `v > 0 and v or 0` has a value of `v` if `v > 0` is true, `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Just write exactly what you said in Lua instead of English:

```
(Cost1 > 0 and Cost1 or 0) + (Cost2 > 0 and Cost2 or 0) + (Cost3 > 0 and Cost3 or 0)
```

Comment: Also, please don't look for "functions" or other snippets to "piece together". Programming is not a puzzle. Try to understand what exactly you are writting in human terms at least. For example I can't figure even slightest relation how https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions can be related to clamping negative values.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do something like this:

```
local value1 = 100
local value2 = -200
local value3 = 200

local value4 = (value1 > 0 and value1 or 0) + (value2 > 0 and value2 or 0) + (value3 > 0 and value3 or 0)
```

The nicest way would be to implement a function that sums up non-negative values

```
function sumOfPositives(tableOfValues)

  local sum = 0

  for i,v in ipairs(tableOfValues) do
    sum = sum + v > 0 and v or 0
  end
  return sum

end
```

This way you can do it for any number of values.

If you prefer to just enter the values without having them in a table you can do what Yu Hao suggested and use the ... argument.